# Конструктор и оператор присваивания в дереве

Tags: c++, дерево

Я написал рабочий копирующий конструктор, оператор копирования, и деструктор для своего дерева, но не могу разобраться с конструктором и оператором присваивания. Пробовал разные варианты, но каждый раз получаю одни и те же ошибки. Также у меня есть рабочая функция swap. Дерево содержит корень и переменную с количеством слов. В чем может быть проблема?

```
tree::tree(tree &&rhs)
{
    tree tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp);
    tree * ptr = &tmp;
    ptr->~tree();
}

tree &tree::operator=(tree &&rhs) {
    tree tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp);
    tree * ptr = &tmp;
    ptr->~tree();
    return *this;
}

void tree::swap(tree &rhs)
{
    std::swap(root, rhs.root);
    std::swap(size, rhs.size);
}
```

Comment: Прямой вызов деструктора не нужен в "нормальном" программировании на C++. Как вы потом собираетесь удалять `ptr`?

Comment: Это просто последнее, что я пробовал. Не утверждаю, что так должно быть.

Comment: Уничтожать объекты после `swap` не нужно. Компилятор сам всё сделает, когда `tmp` выйдет из зоны видимости. А сейчас вы два раза вызываете деструктор.

Comment: Да, судя по всему в этом была проблема, благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, надо разобраться с терминами. Вы пишете "перемещающие" операции (перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания). А версии с `const tree &`, которые у вас уже есть, это "копирующие" операции (копирующий конструктор и копирующий оператор присваивания).

Во-вторых, даже если убрать лишний вызов деструктора, это очень неудачная реализация, потому что вы копируете все дерево. А смысл перемещения как раз в избегании лишних копий. С тем же успехом можно просто не писать перемещающие операции, и компилятор будет сам использовать вместо них копирующие.

Самое минимальное исправление такое:

```
tree::tree(tree &&other) : root(other.root), size(other.size)
{
    other.root = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
}

tree &tree::operator=(tree &&other)
{
    tree tmp(std::move(other));
    swap(*this, tmp); // Или убрать самодельный свап и здесь руками свапнуть поля.
    return *this;
}
```

Но лучше так:

```
tree(tree &&other) noexcept
    : root(std::exchange(other.root, {})), size(std::exchange(other.size, {}))
{}

tree &tree::operator=(tree other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

И убрать копирующее присваивание, потому что это (с параметром `tree` по значению) - универсальное, и работает и для копирования, и для присваивания.

`std::exchange` просто для красоты.

`noexcept` - потому что без него, если положить ваше дерево в стандартный контейнер вроде `std::vector`, он в некоторых ситуациях будет брезговать перемещением и вызывать копирование, чтобы избежать возможных исключений.